# Unable to pass Windows Security authorization popup (protractor)

Tags: internet-explorer, protractor, internet-explorer-11, windows-authentication, basic-authentication

I got stuck with authorization in IE. In my case: I have adfs authorization, which redirect me from my site to adfs, then to my site again redirect me back.

I tried this way:

```
browser.switchTo().alert().sendKeys("Text");
```

But this works only for first input field.

For the second input field:

```
browser.switchTo().alert().sendKeys(protractor.Key.TAB);
```

The driver lost the focus.

I tried the second way with Autoit:

```
helper.loginIE = function(name, password) {
    let formsAuthenticationArea = element.all(by.className(element)).get(0);
    formsAuthenticationArea.click();
   
    browser.call(function () {
        au.Init()
        au.WinWaitActive("Windows Security", "", 3);
        au.Send(name);
        au.Send("{TAB}");
        au.Send(password);
        au.Send("{ENTER}");                      
   })
};
```

Case with Autoit works asynchronously with first click on element.

> node.js - 7.8.1;
>
> protractor - 5.2.2;
>
> selenium-webdriwer - 3.8.1;
>
> IEDriver - 3.7
>
> IE11

```
capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'internet explorer',
    'ignoreProtectedModeSettings': true,
    'disable-popup-blocking': true,
    'enablePersistentHover': true,
    'nativeEvents': false,
    'unexpectedAlertBehaviour': 'ignore',
    'acceptSslCerts': true,
    'trustAllSSLCertificates': true
}
```

The windows security prompt shows:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your auth dialog is not a Browser dialog, so protractor can't auto it natively, but you can use nodejs to call external tool to auto it.

**Option 1)**  Use java.awt.Robot class
Robot is build-in class in JDK, so you no need other library for this solution.

General step as following:

1. Use Robot class capture the auth dialog (maybe by dialog title)
2. Use Robot class to input username and password and click OK button
3. Copy the java class file to your protractor project
4. Use nodejs `process` or `child-process` or other module to execute a Java CMD
   to run the java class

**Disadvantage:** this solution can only work when browser open on local (use directConnet or seleniumAddress is localhost). Because the Robot calss can't operate desktop of remote machine.

To break the `local` limitation of Robot class, one way it's to transfer above class file from script machine to remote browser machine. another possible way is to use [Remote Robot](https://codoid.com/robotil/), I never try it just search in Google before.